# some CSS property working on chrome's console but not on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, console

this is my code,

```
console.log('%c Hello, World!', 'background:linear-gradient(45deg,#FF0099,#493240);padding:5px;font-weight:900;border-radius:5px;')
```

`border-radius`, `padding-block` `border-radius` not working on firefox as the image

[image]

but it's working fine on chromium

[image]

do I have to enable something? or firefox is just limited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox treats messages as inline elements. You should set `display: inline-block` to get the desired behavior. (reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#sect4)